# Clarification of a proof in Herrlich

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

In Herrlich on page 5 he gives a proof of $\textbf{AC} \implies \textbf{WOT}$:

[image]

He does not give a definition of cardinality $|X|$ before this proof and I searched the index for a definition but couldn't find one. Hence, since we are in $\textbf{ZF}$ without $\textbf{C}$ I assume he uses the definition: $\alpha = \min \{\beta \mid \exists s \in V_\beta \text{ s.t. } s \text{ is in bijection with } X \}$ and $|X| = \{ s \in V_\alpha \mid s \text{ is in bijection with } X \} $.

My question then is the following: Why does one resort to Hartogs number for the proof? Can one prove it as follows: Let $\alpha$ as above be the rank of $X$. Then there cannot be an injection from $V_\alpha$ into $X$. Now replace $\aleph$ with $V_\alpha$ in the proof above. Et voilà, we shortened the proof by one definition. What am I missing? I am as always very grateful for your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would argue that you have swapped one definition for another. You have defined V-sets and rank in place of defining Hartogs numbers. That's not necessarily bad, just different, but not really shorter.

Comment: I would interpret $\aleph\not\leq|X|$ simply to mean that there is no injection $\aleph\to X$ (which is after all the defining property of the Hartogs number). If $g(\alpha)\ne\infty$ for all $\alpha$, then the range of $g$ would be (a subset of) $X$, and $g$ would obviously be injective, which contradicts the Hartogs property.

Comment: You only need to be able to interpret $\aleph\not\leq |X|$, and that means simply that there is no injection $j:\aleph\to X$. I am not sure about your rank argument, but Herrlich's proof works even without the axiom of regularity.

Comment: I can't see how your rank argument would work. Suppose $X=\mathcal P(\omega)$. Then $\alpha=\omega+2$ (or something like that; I always tend to get the fenceposts wrong here). However, transfinite induction up to $\alpha$ is _not_ enough to well-order all of $X$ -- there can be an injection $g:\alpha\to X$ even though there is no injection $V_\alpha\to X$. (Even though you can recurse over $V_\alpha$ itself, that would not give you a _well-ordering_).

Comment: @HenningMakholm (at your last comment) I'm sorry in the second sentence of the outline of my argument a typo sneaked in and I wrote $\alpha$ where I meant to write $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @MattN.: The problem is that then you get a function from $V_\alpha$ to $X$, which doesn't really help you well-order $X$. You don't already know any well-ordering of $V_\alpha$, and the function you get isn't even necessarily injective -- there's nothing to prevent $g(\{2n\mid n\in\omega\})$ and $g(\{2n+1\mid n\in \omega\})$ from being the same element of $X$, for example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you! I falsely thought that $V_\alpha$ were well-ordered. I am now trying to see how a transitive set containing a minimal element can be non-well-ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $V_\alpha$ is not good because we don't know whether or not $V_\alpha$ can be well-ordered. In fact, if $X$ cannot be well-ordered and $X\in V_\alpha$ then it is impossible that $V_\alpha$ can be well-ordered.

What Herrlich is doing here is to define a surjection from $\aleph(X)$ onto $X\cup\{\infty\}$ which has the property that the only point in the range which has more than one point in its preimage is $\infty$, so $X$ has a bijection with an ordinal.

Doing the same thing with $V_\alpha$ to begin with will not allow us to conclude that there is *an ordinal* whose range is exactly $X$, which is how we prove that $X$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: I falsely thought $V_\alpha$ were well-ordered. Even now I struggle to see how a transitive set containing a minimal element can be non-well-ordered.

Comment: Well, well-founded is not automatically well-ordered. You have no way of defining a well-ordering of the real numbers, and indeed they might not be well-ordered, but note that $V_{\omega+1}$ has the same cardinality as the real numbers, so we cannot well-order it either in some of the models of $\bf ZF$.

Comment: Ahh--, why did I not think of that! $|V_{\omega + 1}| = |\mathbb R|$ that is, there is a bijection between the two hence $V_{\omega + 1}$ is well-orderable if and only if $\mathbb R$ is. But $\mathbb R$ is well-orderable if and only if $AC$ is assumed. (Is the last one true?) Though, this gives me reason to think that not _all_ of the $V_\alpha$ are well-orderable but some might.

Comment: Well, $\Bbb R$ may be well-orderable and the axiom of choice fails, but it is consistent that it too cannot be well-ordered. And yes, it is perfectly possible that $V_\alpha$ can be well-ordered for $\alpha<\kappa$, but then $V_\kappa$ cannot be well-ordered anymore. It can happen just as easily.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the Hartogs number though, right? We can get rid of this definition since we can appeal to the fact (provable from ZF) that for a set $X$ there is an ordinal $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| \not\le |X|$.

Comment: Of course. But if you have done that, you can just as well say "Let $\alpha$ be the least such ordinal" which is to say $\alpha$ is the Hartogs of $X$.

Comment: Yes but I like short proofs.

Comment: Tough luck. :-) Every proof is short if you have enough assumptions (including prior knowledge of the reader).